# Do external modifiers apply to attacks made with a Ring of the Ram?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, attack

If a character uses a [Ring of the Ram](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/ring-of-the-ram) to make an attack, do external modifiers affect the roll? For example, if the character was under the effect of a [Bless](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/bless) spell, would they apply that to the roll to hit since the spectral ram's head makes the attack, and not the character?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Bless can't help the *Ring of the Ram*

The item description says:

> The ring produces a spectral ram's head and makes **its attack roll with a +7 bonus**.

The ring is doing the attack and it has a +7 bonus, that is a flat bonus and what you should roll. Compare this item to the *Dancing Sword* which says:

> The sword uses your attack roll and ability score modifier to damage rolls.

If *Ring of the Ram* was intended to work this way it would contain this text. It doesn't and can't benefit from bless or your other abilities.